# Tried making coin counter, nothing happens when tested

Tags: lua, roblox

So, I have a game on Roblox currently in development, and I am trying to make a coin counter. Basically, when the coin is collected, a NumberValue in StarterPlayer changes by +1. Then, A TextLabel will loop to check the value of the NumberValue. It will then change the text to display the value of the NumberValue.
However, when I playtest, nothing happens. The counter doesn't change, but the NumberValue does.
Here's the code for the Coin:

```
local coin = script.Parent
local sp = game:GetService("StarterPlayer")
local count = sp.Coins
local p = game:GetService("Players")
local Touched = false

coin.Touched:Connect(function()
    count.Value += 1
    local Sparkles = Instance.new("Sparkles")
    Sparkles.Parent = coin
    Sparkles.SparkleColor = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 0)
    wait(2)
    count.Value += 1
    coin:Destroy()
end)
```

And the code for the TextLabel:

```
local StarterPlayer = game:GetService("StarterPlayer")
local Coins = StarterPlayer.Coins
local CoinLabel = script.Parent

while true do
    CoinLabel.Text = Coins.Value
end
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your TextLabel is never updating is because you have an infinite loop that causes the script to timeout and stop running.

```
while true do
    CoinLabel.Text = Coins.Value
end
```

The simple fix for that is to only update the TextLabel when the NumberValue changes :

```
Coins.Changed:Connect(function()
    CoinLabel.Text = Coins.Value
end)
```

But something else is a little weird too. Objects in [StarterPlayer](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterPlayer) are expected to be copied to each player when they join, but `StarterPlayer.Coins` is not, and as it is right now, it is acting as a global counter for everyone. So your code is modifying the `Coins` object that *would* be copied over to new players, not the one that each player has.
But according to the documentation for StarterPlayer, only a few kinds of objects in StarterPlayer are copied to players.

> - A [StarterPlayerScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterPlayerScripts) instance, with scripts that run once for each player.
> - A [StarterCharacterScripts](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/StarterCharacterScripts) instance, with scripts to add to each player’s character every time they spawn.
> - A [Humanoid](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Humanoid) instance named StarterHumanoid, which will be used as the default humanoid for each player’s character.
> - A [Model](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Model) instance named StarterCharacter, which will be used as the character model for all players

So the NumberValue wouldn't have been copied to each player even if this logic was set up to locate it properly! So, we need to make a few changes :

1. A `Coins` NumberValue needs to be created for each player when they join the game.
2. You need to update the paths to the individual `Coins` NumberValues for each player.
3. Your TextLabel code should listen for the
   [NumberValue.Changed](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/NumberValue/Changed)
   signal, that way your TextLabel will only update when the
   NumberValue does.

So in a Script somewhere like ServerScriptService, add this to create a Coins NumberValue for each Player :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")

Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    -- give each player a Coins object
    local coins = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Value = 0
    coins.Parent = player
end)
```

Next, update the paths in each script to reflect the new location of the object. In the first script, use the player that touched the coin to locate the Player object :

```
local coin = script.Parent
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local Touched = false

coin.Touched:Connect(function(otherPart)
    -- make sure a player touched this
    if otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") == nil then
        return
    end

    -- only call this function once
    if Touched then
        return
    end
    Touched = true

    -- get the player
    local player = Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(otherPart.Parent)
    if not player then
        return
    end

    -- increment the player's coin counter
    player.Coins.Value += 1

    -- show some sparkles
    local Sparkles = Instance.new("Sparkles")
    Sparkles.SparkleColor = Color3.fromRGB(255, 255, 0)
    Sparkles.Parent = coin
    
    -- destroy the coin after a moment
    wait(2)
    coin:Destroy()
end)
```

Finally, update the LocalScript that updates the TextLabel so that it properly finds the NumberValue and updates only when the NumberValue changes :

```
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local player = Players.LocalPlayer
local Coins = player.Coins
local CoinLabel = script.Parent

Coins.Changed:Connect(function()
    CoinLabel.Text = Coins.Value
end)
```